# How to inject Grizzly Request into Jersey ContainerRequestFilter

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, grizzly

I have Jersey being provided by Grizzly.

I have a `ContainerRequestFilter` implementation class.  However this class is created once for all incoming requests.  Therefore doing this:

```
public class EndpointRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Context
    private org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request requestContext;

    public void filter( ContainerRequestContext req ) throws IOException {
       // remove for sake of example
    }
}
```

The `requestContext` is null.  I can inject the context into the actual endpoint being called, but that is rather crude and ugly and really no use to me; as i wish to log various requests.   Ideally would like to get at this `Request` object at the ResponseFilter side of the request.

There has to be an easy way of doing this.  All the questions/answers I have seen thus far doesn't work for Grizzly or injects at the method being called by the REST endpoint.  I don't wish to go around all my hundreds of methods adding this in call just because I want to get the IP address!

So what is the key here?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm surprised you even got the app running, to get to the point where you could find out that request is null. Whenever I tried to run it, I would get an exception on start up, saying that there is no request scope, so the request can't be injected, which is what I expected. Though I couldn't reproduce the NPE, I'm thinking this solution will still solve your problem.

So the `Request` is a request scoped object, as it changes on every request. But the filter is by its nature, a singleton. So what you need to do, is lazily retrieve it. For that, we can use [`javax.inject.Provider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/inject/Provider.html), as a lazy retrieval mechanism.

Going back to the point in my first paragraph, this was the exception I got on start up

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not inside a request scope.

This makes sense, as the `Request` need to be associated with a request scope, and on start up, there is none. A request scope is only present during a request.

So what using the `Provider` does, is allow us to try and grab the `Request` when there is a request scope present.

```
public static class Filter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    private javax.inject.Provider<Request> requestProvider;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        final Request request = requestProvider.get();
        System.out.println(request.getRemoteAddr());
    } 
}
```

I've tested this and it works as expected.

**See Also:**

- [Injecting Request Scoped Objects into Singleton Scoped Object with HK2 and Jersey](http://paulsamsotha.blogspot.com/2015/12/injecting-request-scoped-objects-into.html)

Comment: Good stuff thank you.  The key to getting it working was wrapping it in the Provider class.  That done the trick.