# JAX-RS: Custom SecurityContext has unexpected type when injected into resource method

Tags: java, authentication, jersey, authorization, jax-rs

I have implemented a `ContainerRequestFilter` that performs JWT-based authentication:

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        AuthenticationResult authResult = ...
        if (authResult.isSuccessful()) {
            // Client successfully authenticated.
            // Now update the security context to be the augmented security context that contains information read from the JWT.
            requestContext.setSecurityContext(new JwtSecurityContect(...));
        } else {
            // Client provided no or an invalid authentication token.
            // Deny request by sending a 401 response.
            requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I update the `SecurityContext` of the request, setting it to be an instance of my own custom implementation (`JwtSecurityContext`) if authentication succeeds.  This implementation adds extra authentication and authorization data, which I would like to later access in my subsequent filter(s) and my resource methods.

I have also implemented an `AuthorizationFilter` that is invoked immediately after the `AuthenticationFilter`. Here, I can access the updated `JwtSecurityContext` just fine.

However, I am having problems when I try to inject the `JwtSecurityContext` into a resource (method).

I am currently using Jersey, and [I've read the following in its documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/security.html#d0e12280):

> The `SecurityContext` can be directly retrieved from
>   `ContainerRequestContext` via `getSecurityContext()` method. You can also
>   replace the default `SecurityContext` in a request context with a custom
>   one using the `setSecurityContext(SecurityContext)` method. If you set a
>   custom `SecurityContext` instance in your `ContainerRequestFilter`, this
>   security context instance will be used for injection into JAX-RS
>   resource class fields. This way you can implement a custom
>   authentication filter that may setup your own `SecurityContext` to be
>   used. To ensure the early execution of your custom authentication
>   request filter, set the filter priority to AUTHENTICATION using
>   constants from `Priorities`. An early execution of you authentication
>   filter will ensure that all other filters, resources, resource methods
>   and sub-resource locators will execute with your custom
>   `SecurityContext` instance.

I try to inject the `JwtSecurityContext` into a resource method like so:

```
@Path("/somepath")
public class SomeResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<SomeItem> getItems(@Context SecurityContext securityContext) {
        // securityContext is of type 'SecurityContextInjectee'
    }
}
```

As the comment indicates, the runtime type of the `securityContext` variable becomes `SecurityContextInjectee`. From debugging, I've observed that this wraps a `ContainerRequest` which in turn wraps my `JwtSecurityContext`. However, there are no getters, and I do not want to use reflection to drill down this object hierarchy, so I don't know how to get a hold on my `JwtSecurityContext`.

I have tried changing `@Context SecurityContext securityContext` to `@Context JwtSecurityContext jwtSecurityContext`, but if I do this, the variable becomes `null`. I have also tried field injection, but this behaves the same way.

Am I heading down a wrong path? Should I not be accessing my custom `SecurityContext` in my resource method? One alternative could be to wrap all my data in the `Principal` implementation I return from `getUserPrincipal` in my `JwtSecurityContext`. I suppose the proxy (`SecurityContextInjectee`) would forward the call to its underlying `JwtSecurityContext` and hence return my `Principal`, but I am not sure, and ultimately I would prefer to use my `JwtSecurityContext` instead of wrapping these values in a `Principal` implementation.

Comment: @peeskillet Interesting, I didn't know I could inject the ContainerRequestContext. I suppose I will be able to call getSecurityContext on that and have my custom security context returned.

Comment: @peeskillet Yes, injecting ContainerRequestContext and calling getSecurityContext on that instance does indeed return the JwtSecurityContext. Thanks! If you like, you can post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can inject the `ContainerRequestContext` (as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27666797/2587435)) and just get the `SecurityContext` from there.

```
public List<SomeItem> getItems(@Context ContainerRequestContext context) {
    JwtSecurityContext sec = (JwtSecurityContext)context.getSecurityContext();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Oh by the way, do you happen to know a thing or two about JPA? I am still looking for an answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38664913/jpa-locking-when-performing-an-indirect-insertion

Comment: I know some JPA, but its not something I use everyday. I think that question is a little advanced for my knowledge :-(

Comment: Okay, just thought it'd give it a shot :). Thanks again!

Comment: For future reference: Unfortunately this strategy does not seem to work in sub-resource locators -- the type of the security context is WebComponentX on my Jersey+Glassfish setup. I would like to prevent access to the entire sub resource based on checking a condition in the my custom security context, but I guess I will just have to perform the check in all methods of the sub resource instead.

Comment: @peeskillet, Any idea why there are two `SecurityContext`? I am mainly asking because I had to implement my own `SecurityContext` and set it during a `ContainerRequestFilter`, and I wanted to access it inside a `Singletong` bean later to find from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34747574/jersey-2-context-injection-based-upon-httprequest-without-singleton) for you that `SecurityContext` is `proxiable`, while `ContainerRequestContext` is not?

Comment: @fujy What about `ContainerRequest`? It the concrete implementation of `ContainerRequestContext`. If it doesn't work, try to inject it with `Provider` as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37745362/2587435)

Comment: @peeskillet Thanks for the fast reply, `ContainerRequest` didn't work, it stayed as the same object for all requests, so it had the same `SecurityContext ` object with the first entered authentication credentials. Actually `ContainerRequest` and `ContainerRequestContext` had exactly the same object instance, since as you said that it just a concrete implementation of the [later](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ContainerRequest.java)

Comment: @peeskillet I tried the provider solution, but it didn't work, or maybe I didn't implement it the correct way, I tried again with `rs.core.SecurityContext`, I was able to see in debug that it is an instance of my own implementation `MySecurityContext` if I try to call any method inside it, but still I was not able to get a reference of it, so I tried casting, to find that Java doesn't allow casting of proxy classes, Last, I had to change `MySecurityContext.getUserPrincipal()` to return an object of a subclass of `java.security.Principal` that holds my customized user information, and it works.