# @ConvertGroup based on parameter

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I'm looking to implement bean validation with groups based on parameter. The idea is to have methods with signature like:

```
@POST
@Path("/id-{id}")
public SomeDTO updateProducer(@PathParam("id") String id, @MatrixParam("update") Class<ConvertGroupTarget> update, @Valid SomeDTO data);
```

This would serve as an equivalent of explicit `ConvertGroup` declaration, such as:

```
@POST
@Path("/id-{id}")
public SomeDTO updateProducer(@PathParam("id") String id, @Valid @ConvertGroup(from=Default.class, to=/*some class that implements ConvertGroupTarget*/) SomeDTO data);
```

Is this even possible at all? We're using `Jersey` with `hibernate-validator`.

**EDIT**: the purpose of this all. Say I want to validate beans based on some validation group for specific purposes. For example, some bean can have different rules that apply to creating and updating it. So the bean declaration looks like this:

```
class SomeDTO {
    @NotNull(groups = {Create.class, Update.class})
    private String id;

    @NotNull(groups = {Create.class, Update.class})
    private String name;

    @NotNull(groups = Update.class)
    private String something;

    //getters, setters etc.
}
```

The classes Create and Update are just some marker classes/interfaces to provide typed declaration of the groups.

Now, say the API user is creating an entity and he does 
`POST /id-X123/;update=create`. Here I just want to validate the ID and the name, but don't really care about the `something` property of the bean. But when API user wants to update the bean, the API should require that he specifies even the `something` property. This is normally done by converting the validation group - `@ConvertGroup(from = Default.class, to = Create.class)` for creating and `@CovertGroup(from = Default.class, to = Update.class)` for updating. However, I'm looking to skip the explicit declaration of a `ConvertGroup` annotation and do this programatically based on parameter.

Comment: @peeskillet updated the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConvertGroup defines static group conversions so you won't have the ability to parameterize them. You define them once and for all.

I think what you want to do is to call the Validator with a group. I don't use Jersey so I don't know if they have a hook for it but what you should look for is this:

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<SomeDTO>> violations =
    validator.validate(someDTO); // validate the default group

Set<ConstraintViolation<SomeDTO>> violations =
    validator.validate(someDTO, Update.class); // validate the Update group
```

Comment: It's entirely possible that I'm thinking about this all wrong. What I probably really need is some kind of validation interceptor that would redefine the group based on a parameter with some other defined annotation, for example `@UpdateGroup` or something simmilar. However, I still can't find a solution for Jersey.

Comment: @cypher I was just digging through [the source code](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/ext/bean-validation/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/validation), and there is a [`ValidationInterceptor`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/spi/ValidationInterceptorContext.java) you can implement and register. You can inject `UriInfo` into your implementation to get the matrix parameters and query parameters. I've tested it an it works.

Comment: You will need to inject the UriInfo with `Provider`, as mentioned in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37745362/2587435).

Comment: I've found the same thing, but did you somehow manage to make Jersey validate a particular group? I've been digging through the same thing and came around a sentence in docs that states group-based validation is not available in Jersey. [`Jersey does not support, and doesn't validate, constraints placed on constructors and Bean Validation groups (only Default group is supported at the moment).`](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html)

Comment: @cypher I still don't really understand the whole group thing. I really have only use basic bean validation stuff. I thought maybe you could do manual validation here. One thing I'm not sure about is on success, the real validator will still be called, so it's double validating. I'm not sure if you can just cause the validation process to exit from the interceptor without throwing an exception.

Comment: @peeskillet I can, but it's specifically stated in docs that I shouldn't - `To allow further validation processing, every and each implementation
     * must invoke {@link ValidationInterceptorContext#proceed()} method.`. I'm now starting to believe that the only clean solution may be using a custom ValidationFeature, although it does seem like major overkill for such a simple thing.

Comment: @peeskillet ended up writing own implementation of ValidationFeature and disabling the default as Jersey simply doesn't support it. Thanks for your help.